# ¿Cómo solucionar el error 'Unknown column 'userId' in 'field list'' en Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, sql, nodejs, sequelize.js

Estoy tratando de utilizar el método "findAll()" de Sequelize en mi modelo de Usuario y estoy recibiendo un mensaje de error que dice:

> sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'userId' in 'field list'",
> sql: 'SELECT `id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `bithDate`, `phone`, `email`, `password`, `admin`, `userImageId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`,
> `deletedAt`, `userId` FROM `users` AS `User`;'

Sin embargo, la columna 'userId' no existe en mi modelo de Sequelize, y tampoco ha sido creada en la base de datos en ningún momento.

A continuación, presento el código que estoy utilizando:

> Migrations:

```
'use strict';

/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
      },
      lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
      },
      bithDate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: false
      },
      phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
        allowNull: true
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false
      },
      admin: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false
      },
      userImageId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
          model: "usersImages",
          key: "id"
        }
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      deletedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: true,
      }
    });
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
};
```

> Model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    let alias = "User";
    let cols = {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull: false
        },
        bithDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
            allowNull: false
        },
        phone: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(30),
            allowNull: true
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false
        },
        admin: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false
        },
        userImageId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            references: {
                model: "usersImages",
                key: "id"
            }
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        updatedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        deletedAt: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true,
        }
    };

    let config = {
        tableName: "users"
    }

    const User = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config)

    User.associate = (models) => {
        User.belongsTo(models.UserImage, {
            as: "image",
            foreignKey: "userImageId"
        })

        User.hasMany(models.Address, {
            as: "addresses",
            foreignKey: "userId"
        })

        User.hasMany(models.Order, {
            as: "orders",
            foreignKey: "userId"
        })

        User.belongsTo(models.Cart, {
            as: "cart",
            foreignKey: "userId"
        })

        User.belongsToMany(models.Product, {
            as: "favoritesProducts",
            foreignKey: "userId",
            otherkey: "productId",
            through: "favoritesproducts",
        })

        User.belongsToMany(models.Product, {
            as: "productsSalved",
            foreignKey: "userId",
            otherkey: "productId",
            through: "savedproducts",
        })
    }

    return User
}
```

Comment: Encontré la solución en este artículo:
[Difference between HasOne and BelongsTo in Sequelize ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565360/difference-between-hasone-and-belongsto-in-sequelize-orm/34570497#34570497?newreg=0c971c94303a44d7b352b4d7f14123e7)

Comment: Pon el contenido de ese enlace como respuesta, y luego [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer). Piénsalo: si alguien llega a tener un problema similar, y encuentra el enlace pero roto, ¿cómo podrá saber finalmente cuál era la respuesta? No olvides además leer [answer].